# Javascript Regular Expression that match accent and none-accented version of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking for a way using regular expression that will match accented and none accented version of a string using Javascript.

I'm extending jQuery-ui's autocomplete to add bold html tag around words in the autocomplete, here's my code:

```
<script>
 // Add feature to autocomplete to make the searched query in bold letter
    $.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
        _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
            var searchMask = this.element.val();
            var replaceMask = "<b style=\"\">$&</b>";
            var splittedMask = searchMask.split(' ');
            var html = regEx = '';
            // Fix I added so it works with multiple words.
            splittedMask.forEach(function(word){
                if (word.length >= 2){
                    // Here is the part that should interest you
                    regEx = new RegExp(word, "ig");
                    if (html == ''){
                        html = item.label.replace(regEx, replaceMask);
                    } else {
                        html = html.replace(regEx, replaceMask);
                    }
                } else {
                    html = item.label;
                }
            });

            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append($("<span></span>").html(html))
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
    });
</script>
```

So right now, if I write (for example) Montréal, it works and finds out Montréal in my menu, but if I write Montreal, it will not be found by the `RegEx`.

I've looked online but couldn't find the right RegEx.

Comment: You will need to normalize input first as there is no way to match `é` with `e`. You may consider replacing all `e` with `[eé]` in the pattern though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is actually a good idea man, I did it with e to [eé] and a to [aà]. You should do an answer with it I believe it's a good solution to my problem

Comment: I added an answer with this suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider [normalizing the input first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript) as there is no way to match `é` with `e` with a regex.

Alternatively, you may consider replacing all `e` with `[eé]` in your patterns  (it will be safe you you only build the pattern out of literal strings). You may use an associative array where keys are used to search for a letter and values containing the character class to match all the accented variations.

Answer (score 2):

It's not straightforward - basically the only way to do it is to replace the accented characters with non-accented versions before passing them into your RegEx.

This article has some example code (look for the "Hey man, I'm only here for the copy/paste" section), plus a lot of caveats: [Accent Folding for Auto-Complete](https://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete)

Comment: I saw that before sadly, it remove the accent and then attempt a search but then my Montréal will not be found, only Montreal will be found